# Best way to display, modify and then store data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssis, reporting

Currently I have several machines that output data in a CSV file. I'm putting a system in place to import this CSV file into a SQL Server database using SSIS. Once the data resides on the SQL Server I would like to then display the data as a report (preferably SSRS), however the hangup I'm having is my end users then want to modify the data displayed in the report and then re-upload this finished report into the database. Ideally I leave the raw data in its raw format and store any modified data separately. What are some potential methods for accomplishing this?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. This question is entirely too open ended for this forum. There are no right or wrong answers here.

Comment: Hello and thank you. I realize it is open ended. I'm a fairly new developer and trying to get an idea of possible solutions. I don't believe it is good practice to try and have an SSRS report modify the database directly. One option I have is to export the report to Excel, have the user modify what they want and then import the finished report back into a new table.

Comment: Like you said a report is for...well reporting. It is not a UI. Not only is that not best practice I don't think it is even possible. Exporting to excel is probably doable. But then this isn't really a report if the user can just change the data to produce the output they want.

Comment: Personally, I would question why they want to modify the data. I've found, in the past, that the majority of times it is for 2 reasons: 1. They want to *"adjust"* the figures to be more favourable. 2. To get further consumable information from them. If the former, well, that's a concern unto itself; "fudging" of figures is bad (and i have seen it far too many times). If the latter, then perhaps the report (SSRS), should be working out that data for them instead; or the T-SQL used to generate the dataset. Either way, like Sean said, this is far too broad at the moment.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I don't like that they want to modify the data either. However I'm working with researchers who want the report to format the data a specific way that they then want to analyze and aggregate until they're hearts content. I'm also trying to change their mindset of only using Excel for everything (including data storage). I may not be able to get around Excel for their modifications, but I do intend to keep the modified data separate from the raw dataset.

Comment: … the best way to accomplish this is called "create an application". It can be readable Visual Basic or uglyfied JavaScript, it can be web-based or a Windows application. One day, you and your users will have to say "good bye" to beloved Excel. You might have read somewhere that SSIS can import CSV files into a database and that SSRS can be used to retrieve data from a database, but they can't replace a user interface to let the users edit the data in a user-friendly way. You will have to bite the bullet and either put some effort in learning to program or hire a developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a custom app instead of SSRS that displays the report in an editable data grid.

You could also create a custom app that lets users import data via excel, so if they export your SSRS report to Excel, they can edit the Excel doc and then upload it to save their changes to your database.

Comment: Agreed. Those are the two best ways. My only contribution is that creating an application to allow users to modify the data on-the-fly will be more work intensive than allowing for the user to provide corrected data via the same file import process.